# Non fixed number of substitutions with a single regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to match a c function with any number of parameters and do a substitution for each. Is it possible?

An example:

I would like the  regular expression to match

```
void functionName(int a);
```

and convert it to type: int, paranName: a

I would like the regular expression to match also:

```
void functionName(int a, int b)
```

and convert it to type: int, paramName: a,  type: int, paramName: b

I know how to do substitutions, etc... but don't know it it is possible to do them in a non fixed way.

Comment: You didn't say what language you need the answer to be in, or even whether it needs to be coded.  This kind of thing can be done in editors like `emacs` even without writing any code.

Comment: Well, I have done it with some c# scripting using regex. Just wanted to know if there was a better/easier option. So, I thought about doing this with just a regex without any more coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the case-insensitive and . does not match newlines:

Find: `(?:[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)+\()?([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)(?:\);?)?`

Replace: `Type: \1, paramName: \2`

I used Notepad++, but I think it would work in C# too.